# What is the state of the art algorithm for diagonalizing real symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algorithms, diagonalization

There are many methods for diagonalizing matrices; probably the most widely used is the combination of household transformations and the QR algorithm.

- **Is there any superior method for diagonalizing large, non-sparse real symmetric matrices?**

Superiority can be a bit muddy, so I define it as fast, numerically stable, does not require large amounts of extra memory, and lends itself to parallelization and vectorization.

- Crosspost: [SciComp.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/23343/39670)

Comment: The established standard should still be to do a transform to Hessenberg, that is here tridiagonal, form, and then apply the multi-bulge-chasing variant of the multi-shift Francis algorithm.